# How to use use Network System in Unity 2019.4

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently i'm using Unity 2018.1.4f1, I'm trying to migrate the project to Unity 2019.4.1f1, but `Unity.System.NetworkManager` is not supported

The problem occurs at the modules:

```
NetworkDisconnection
NetworkMessageInfo
NetworkPlayer
```

Can I use this module in version 2019.4?

Answer (score 0):

The old Unet system is being deprecated and has now moved to a separate package that you need to install from the `package manager` (Window > package manager) solely to support people already using it that want to update to a newer unity. Note that new projects shouldn't use it. The package you'll want to install is called `Multiplayer HLAPI`.

If you can not see the package in the package manager make sure you have selected "all packages"

From the documentation [found here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingHLAPI.html)

> Unity’s multiplayer High Level API (HLAPI) is a system for building multiplayer capabilities for Unity games. It is built on top of the lower level transport real-time communication layer, and handles many of the common tasks that are required for multiplayer games. While the transport layer supports any kind of network topology, the HLAPI is a server authoritative system; although it allows one of the participants to be a client and the server at the same time, so no dedicated server process is required. Working in conjunction with the internet services, this allows multiplayer games to be played over the internet with little work from developers.

Answer (score 0):

Better you try mirror since unity's inbuilt network is being deprecated. It is same as unity's network. You can find mirror in unity's asset store.